# Read text file and comparing its contents with multiple CSV files

Tags: python, csv, text, directory

This is how the python script is supposed to work:-
It will check the content of "words.txt" in all csv files within a folder and extract the result from beginning to where there is exact match found of the line by line content of "words.txt".

[Here is the file structure and the code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vpeid1l19cxyov/staticVersion.zip?dl=0) that works for two CSV files.

```html
# Tested on Python 2.7

import csv
from itertools import chain


with open("words.txt", "rb") as keywords, open('csv1.csv', 'rb') as g, open('csv2.csv', 'rb') as f, open('csv1_modify.csv', 'wb') as myfile1, open('csv2_modify.csv', 'wb') as myfile2:

# Step1: Read contents of keywords.tex in variables
 ky = list(keywords.readlines())
 ky1, ky2 = ky[0], ky[1]

# Step2: Read and process folding umbrella-sort-highest.csv
 reader = csv.reader(g)
 umbrella_list = list(reader)
 list1 = filter(lambda e: e[0] in ky1, umbrella_list)

 list2 = list(chain(*list1))
 # or better: (available since Python 2.6)
 # print list(chain.from_iterable(list1))

 ind_prt1 = umbrella_list.index(list2) +1 
 mylist1 = umbrella_list[:ind_prt1]

 for r in mylist1:
  wr = csv.writer(myfile1, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
  wr.writerow(r)

# Step3: Read and process lego minecraft-sort-highest.csv
 reader = csv.reader(f)
 minecraft_list = list(reader)
 list3 = filter(lambda e: e[0] in ky2, minecraft_list)

 list4 = list(chain(*list3))
 # or better: (available since Python 2.6)
 # print list(chain.from_iterable(list4))

 ind_prt2 = minecraft_list.index(list4) +1 
 mylist2 = minecraft_list[:ind_prt2]

 for r in mylist2:
  wr = csv.writer(myfile2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
  wr.writerow(r)

print "Task completed, check your working directory."
```

**Question:** Now, the question is to make the script work for multiple keywords content of "words.txt" on multiple CSV files within directory dynamically?

It shouldn't be limited to a specific number of keywords or files, but it should dynamically respond to any amount of keywords and files. [See what is in my mind](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8dimu798u8z7r4v/dynamicVersion.zip?dl=0)

That is it!

Comment: It's a better idea to upload the files to gist.github.com since then others won't have to download a file from you.

Comment: .zip files can't be viewed in Dropbox. Would be better if you [edit]ed your question and put all the related code **in it**.

Comment: As suggested, I have added the code snippet that works with python2 on two static files.